# Getting the distance b/w float and its neighbor

Tags: c, bit

This is my function that takes in the bits of a float, and returns the distance between the next float and the given float. In it, I have assumed the float is 32 bits. My process was to extract the mantissa and exponent, increment the mantissa, increment the exponent if it overflows, reconstruct the value and subtract the distance between them.

I have a feeling I may be overcomplicating things, and the function doesn't seem to be making use of the bitwise operators used correctly, even though I have used an algorithm similar to this before. What is going wrong here? It seems straightforward enough?

```
    unsigned int get_distance(unsigned int bitnumber)
    {
    unsigned int mantissa = 0xff;
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            if (((1 << i) & bitnumber) != 0) mantissa = mantissa | 1 << i;
    }

    mantissa = mantissa++; // increment the mantissa

    unsigned int exponent = 0xff;
    for (int i = 24; i < 31; i++) {
                    if (((1 << i) & floatbits) != 0) exponent = exponent | 1 << i;
    }


    if (mantissa != mantissa) exponent++; // if it overflows, increment the exponent too.

    // create complete bit pattern
    unsigned int final = 0xff;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {

            if (i < 24) {
                    if (((1 << i) & mantissa) != 0) final = final | 1 << i;
            }

            if (i >= 24 && i < 31) {
                    if (((1 << i) & exponent) != 0) final = final | 1 << i;
            }

            if (i == 32) {
                    if (((1 << i) & bitnumber) != 0) final = final | 1 << i;
            }
    }

    // get difference b/w original float and new float
    unsigned int result = final - bitnumber;
    return result;
    }
```

Comment: Should be equal to `FLT_EPSILON`, from `float.h`, right?

Comment: I don't think so as the gaps change depending on what float you put in.

Comment: `FLT_EPSILON` is the difference between `1.0f` and the smallest value greater than `1.0f`. This difference is different (no pun intended) for larger values. For example, the next value after `16777216.0f` is `16777217.0f`, an entire difference of `1.0f`

Comment: Also, you can take advantage of the fact that the exponent bits are right above the mantissa bits, so a mantissa overflow can "automatically" overflow into the exponent.

Comment: Sorry, as I'm new to this, can you explain this (possibly in the form of an answer) a little more. How would I use the value of FLT_EPSILON to figure out the "absolute distance" b/w two floats?

Comment: You wouldn't. `FLT_EPSILON` is not relevant to your interests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you are unnecessarily complicating the extraction of the various fields (and, you're doing so incorrectly). A much easier way to do this is:

```
unsigned int exponent = (bitnumber >> 23) & ((1 << 8) - 1);
unsigned int mantissa = bitnumber & ((1 << 23) - 1);
```

Basically, you shift `bitnumber` left until the LSB of your desired field is bit 0, and then bitwise-and out just the bits you want. The expression `((1 << N) - 1)` is a mask consisting of `N` 1s in the lowest bits.

Second, the line `mantissa = mantissa++;` is actually *undefined behavior*, since the post-increment and assignment will both try to assign a value to `mantissa`. Instead, you just want `mantissa++`.

Next, the check for overflow will never pass, as `mantissa != mantissa` will always be false. Instead, you want to check if bit 23 or higher is set, which can be done with `mantissa >= (1 << 23)`. I'd also recommend grouping this statement with the aforementioned increment, so you have

```
mantissa++;
if (mantissa >= (1 << 23))
    exponent++;
```

Finally, reconstructing the new value is as simple as:

```
unsigned int final = (exponent << 23) | mantissa;
```

Note, however, that if `exponent` is too large, this will result in a different float than you expect (namely, a negative one). There are also a few other boundary cases regarding infinity/NaN and unnormalized numbers, but more than likely you won't run into them.

To actually use this, you'll need to do some pointer conversion, like this:

```
float value = 1.0f; // for example
unsigned int *up = (unsigned int *)&value; // NOTE: this might trigger undefined behavior
unsigned int next = next_value(*up); // next_value is a better name for your function than get_distance
float *fp = (float *)&next; // again, this may be UB
float difference = *fp - value; // this is what you want
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if I do have to check for boundary cases, why would that make any difference? The only difference for instance for denormalized numbers is the 0s in the exponent. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Also, is the logic here for finding the gap correct? How would I find the distance b/w the two as that is what the function needs to return? I've used simple subtraction above.

Comment: Denormalized numbers don't have the implied leading 1 for the mantissa. Also, when exponent is all 1s, the mantissa encodes infinity and NaN, so your differences will be wrong.

Comment: In addition to my question above - so this doesn't work on denormalized values? How would I special case that?

Comment: See my edit for an example usage. Also, I'm not 100% sure about denormalized values - it may technically be correct.